# How does Google's gfeed work

Tags: jquery, rss, cross-domain

I've been trying to get the [jDigiClock jQuery plugin](http://www.radoslavdimov.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-digiclock/) to work without having to use a proxy and noticed that Google's gfeed service (jquery.gfeed.js) doesn't require anything server-side and it's able to pull XML data from cross-domain sites. Is it possible to convert the jDigiClock to use that same functionality? Thanks.

Comment: is jsonp not an option in this case? btw, thanks for the clock :) love it.

Comment: not familiar with jsonp; how would that work with the clock?

Comment: we pull crosss site json data using jsonp. looks like its not an option here unless one fork the plugin and work on it

Comment: found this that works: http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-weather-widget.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gfeed API contacts Google to get the feeds. And since the JavaScript code also comes from Google, it doesn't have any cross-domain problem. In short: it needs a server-side component to work, but the server-side component is hosted by Google and not by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, JB. Is there a widget that uses the same technique to display weather information instead of news feeds? In other words, a widget that doesn't need any server-side stuff from us. Thanks.